# How to return true if there is a duplicate object in ArrayList?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, boolean, duplicates

Writing a method in Java that looks through an `ArrayList` of objects (specifically "card" objects, that contain the number and suit of the card) that has been filled with random cards. The method returns a boolean value whether the `ArrayList` contains a duplicate.

So far I've tried a `for` loop within a `for` loop, but I didn't get very far.

Also, I need another method that returns the duplicate card, but I need to finish this first method first before I attempt that.

Comment: Post what you have so far...

Comment: Create a temporary copy of one of the lists then use `removeAll` passing in the second list, if the size changes, you have duplicate items...

Comment: y not sort them and compare one by one!

Comment: When you say duplicate, do you mean rank only? There are no cards with the same rank and suit in a standard deck.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you would generally find duplicates:

```
public static bool findDuplicates(List<Card> listContainingDuplicates) {

        final Set<Card> set1 = new HashSet<Card>();

        for (Card yourCard : listContainingDuplicates) {
            if (!set1.add(yourCard)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your algorithm is limited in space, sort the list and then find duplicated values in liner time. The total time complexity of this algorithm is O(nlogn).

```
public boolean hadDuplicatedCards(List<Card> cards) {
        Collections.sort(cards);
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.size() - 1; i++) {
            if(cards.get(i).equals(cards.get(i+1))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Otherwise, `new` a `HashSet`, and `add` cards one by one, if an equal card already present in `HashSet`, `add` method will return `true`.

BTW, In the sort approach, your `Card` class need to implement `Comparable` interface, and don't forget to override the `equals` method. 
In the `HashSet` approach, you only need to override the `equals` method. But be aware that the `HashSet` approach needs extra O(n) space.

Thanks for  PM 77-1's comments.

Comment: As OP states: "... "card" objects, that contain **the number and suit** of the card".  So for your method to work `Card` needs to implement `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Nope. For `HashSet` approach we need just `equals` method, that we can  reasonably expect a class to have.  Do not need `Comparable` here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html you could just use indexOf and lastIndexOf.

In psuedo code:

```
myfunct(list, obj){
    if(list.indexOf(obj) == list.lastIndexOf(obj))
        return False;
    else
        return True; // Two or more ...
}
```

Comment: Method should check whether there's **a** duplicate.

Comment: ah my bad ... i go with hashmap then

Comment: I think you just need to put it in a loop and stop at the first `true`.  I like the idea itself. It does not require extra space, though could be a hog on time.